# replace duplicate dates with weekly sequence order in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, zoo, lubridate

I'm working on a similar kind of data

```
structure(list(id = c("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", 
"aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "ccc", 
"ccc", "ccc", "ccc", "ccc", "ccc"), score = c(100.5, 110.46, 
113.35, 128.214, 130.123, 134.56, 139.56, 20.5, 21.465, 30.436, 
49.24, 60.325, 66.4, 70.25, 99.43, 70.35, 64.4, 60.325, 55.35, 
42.35), date = c("2018-02-25", "2018-02-25", "2018-02-25", "2018-02-25", 
"2018-02-25", "2018-02-25", "2018-02-25", "2018-03-18", "2018-03-18", 
"2018-03-18", "2018-03-18", "2018-03-18", "2018-03-18", "2018-03-18", 
"2018-04-22", "2018-04-22", "2018-04-22", "2018-04-22", "2018-04-22", 
"2018-04-22")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

I would like to replace the duplicated date values by weekly sequence of dates grouped by their id for a larger data set.
My sample output:

```
id      score        date
aaa    100.5      2018-02-25
aaa    110.46     2018-03-04
aaa    113.35     2018-03-11
aaa    128.214    2018-03-18
aaa    130.123    2018-03-25
aaa    134.56     2018-04-01
aaa    139.56     2018-04-08
bbb    20.5       2018-03-18
bbb    21.465     2018-03-25
bbb    30.436     2018-04-01
bbb    49.24      2018-04-08
bbb    60.325     2018-04-15
bbb    66.4       2018-04-22
bbb    70.25      2018-04-29
ccc    99.43      2018-04-22
ccc    70.35      2018-04-29
ccc    64.4       2018-05-06
ccc    60.325     2018-05-13
ccc    55.35      2018-05-20
ccc    42.35      2018-05-27
```

Basically it should take the first date grouped by id(read dynamically) and fill the following rows with dates in weekly sequence manner.I appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm not certain I follow (or perhaps "agree") with your logic. The data clearly has a unique date for each id, and you want to change the values of `date` from what is there? If the data is coming to you this way, then perhaps you need to adjust how the data is being created. If not, then perhaps we should focus on how you are importing the data. Having said that ... I'd think `by` or `dplyr::group_by` (and `dplyr::n`) would be one way to warp this data.

Comment: Can you share the solution using dplyr@r2evans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a weekly sequence withing group

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id, date) %>%
  mutate(new_date= seq(as.Date(date[1]), length.out = n(), by = "week"))

#   id    score date       new_date  
#   <chr> <dbl> <chr>      <date>    
# 1 aaa   100.  2018-02-25 2018-02-25
# 2 aaa   110.  2018-02-25 2018-03-04
# 3 aaa   113.  2018-02-25 2018-03-11
# 4 aaa   128.  2018-02-25 2018-03-18
# 5 aaa   130.  2018-02-25 2018-03-25
# 6 aaa   135.  2018-02-25 2018-04-01
# 7 aaa   140.  2018-02-25 2018-04-08
# 8 bbb    20.5 2018-03-18 2018-03-18
# 9 bbb    21.5 2018-03-18 2018-03-25
#10 bbb    30.4 2018-03-18 2018-04-01
#11 bbb    49.2 2018-03-18 2018-04-08
#12 bbb    60.3 2018-03-18 2018-04-15
#13 bbb    66.4 2018-03-18 2018-04-22
#14 bbb    70.2 2018-03-18 2018-04-29
#15 ccc    99.4 2018-04-22 2018-04-22
#16 ccc    70.4 2018-04-22 2018-04-29
#17 ccc    64.4 2018-04-22 2018-05-06
#18 ccc    60.3 2018-04-22 2018-05-13
#19 ccc    55.4 2018-04-22 2018-05-20
#20 ccc    42.4 2018-04-22 2018-05-27
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using

Your data:

```
x <- structure(list(id = c("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", 
"aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "ccc", 
"ccc", "ccc", "ccc", "ccc", "ccc"), score = c(100.5, 110.46, 
113.35, 128.214, 130.123, 134.56, 139.56, 20.5, 21.465, 30.436, 
49.24, 60.325, 66.4, 70.25, 99.43, 70.35, 64.4, 60.325, 55.35, 
42.35), date = c("2018-02-25", "2018-02-25", "2018-02-25", "2018-02-25", 
"2018-02-25", "2018-02-25", "2018-02-25", "2018-03-18", "2018-03-18", 
"2018-03-18", "2018-03-18", "2018-03-18", "2018-03-18", "2018-03-18", 
"2018-04-22", "2018-04-22", "2018-04-22", "2018-04-22", "2018-04-22", 
"2018-04-22")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
x$date <- as.Date(x$date)
```

One method:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(date = seq(date[1], by = "week", length.out = n())) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 20 x 3
#    id    score date      
#    <chr> <dbl> <date>    
#  1 aaa   100.  2018-02-25
#  2 aaa   110.  2018-03-04
#  3 aaa   113.  2018-03-11
#  4 aaa   128.  2018-03-18
#  5 aaa   130.  2018-03-25
#  6 aaa   135.  2018-04-01
#  7 aaa   140.  2018-04-08
#  8 bbb    20.5 2018-03-18
#  9 bbb    21.5 2018-03-25
# 10 bbb    30.4 2018-04-01
# 11 bbb    49.2 2018-04-08
# 12 bbb    60.3 2018-04-15
# 13 bbb    66.4 2018-04-22
# 14 bbb    70.2 2018-04-29
# 15 ccc    99.4 2018-04-22
# 16 ccc    70.4 2018-04-29
# 17 ccc    64.4 2018-05-06
# 18 ccc    60.3 2018-05-13
# 19 ccc    55.4 2018-05-20
# 20 ccc    42.4 2018-05-27
```

Comment: because OP says `I would like to replace the duplicated date values`,so I am grouping `date` as well. There could be more unique dates in one `id`.

Comment: Good thought ... I interpreted it as *"all dates for an `id` are duplicated"*, whereas you interpreted it as *"all duplicated dates for each `id`"*. They both work given assumptions, nice thought RonakShah.